Android Kotlin ScanFilter Builder class not functioning
As stated above, I'm trying to use ScanFilter.Builder() to construct a filter for my bluetooth application, and it gives an unresolved reference error.
I have ScanFilter properly imported, and the import suggestion (in the image) does nothing; that is, it keeps the error there and doesn't make any changes.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
